# Surface electric current flows

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

All the models of electric current flow I have seen used in the texts I have seen are models where the current flows in a curve - let us call it $\gamma$ -, and for which, for example, the magnetic field is $$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{d\boldsymbol{\ell}'\times(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')}{\|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\|^3}$$and models where the current is distributed in a tridimensional region $V$ and for which the magnetic field is $$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_V\frac{\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r}')\times(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')}{\|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\|^3}dV'.$$

I suppose that we could think about flows of electric current confined ina surface, for example imaging all electrons moving on the surface, but, although, for example, I have seen models of surfaces $\Sigma$ endowed with a charge $\int_{\Sigma}\rho\,d\sigma$ where $\rho$ is surface density, I have never seen a text talking about surface flows of current. Are they used in physics and, if they are, how is the magnetic field defined? Thank you for any answer!

Comment: What stops you from specializing the volume version of Biot-Savart to a sheet, where J(r') is zero everywhere but on the sheet?

Comment: @CuriousOne Something like $\int_{\Sigma}\frac{\rho\mathbf{v}_d\times(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')}{\|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'\|^3}d\sigma'$ where $\mathbf{v}_d$ is drift velocity and $\rho$ surface density of current, I suppose... But I wonder whether that is ever used...

Comment: One of the standard textbook problems is the rotating homogeneously charged sphere. This kind of problem is also common in the design of electronic circuits and you can find engineering software that solves these kinds of problems for thin current sheets (also known as printed circuit boards :-)).